# Write a Query in criteria builder for join combined with or condition

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, criteria, query-builder

```
select * from person as p join personal_information as pi on p.id=pi.personId
where p.cellNumber='1234567890' or pi.cellNUmber='123456789';
```

Here is the structure for Person table:

```
`id` `name` `cellNumber` `emailAddress`
```

Here is the structure for personal_information table:

```
`id` `personId`(foreign key from Person table) `cellNumber`
```

Now I am in a situation where I have to fetch person who has a particular cell number. Lets say based on my query it is 123456789
And it is possible that Person table has a cellNumber as 000000000
so the record would be like:

`101 John 000000000 'abc@gmail.com'`

but personal_information table has 5 records that have that cellNumber
e.g.
personal_information table

```
1 101 123456789
2 102 123456789
3 103 123456789
4 104 123456789
5 105 123456789
```

Now based on cellNumber I want all these 5 records from Person table to be fetched. 
But its quite possible that the number matches only in Person table i.e.

Person table

```
109 John 123456789 'john@gmail.com'
```

So this time I would like to get the record from Person table

The query that I have written above solves my purpose, but I want to do it with Criteria builder
Here is the relationship between Person and personal_information on Entity level

```
public class Person {

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "person", optional = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
private PersonalInformation personalInformation;

//getters and setters

}

public class PersonalInformation() {

@OneToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "personId", referencedColumnName = "id")
private Person person;
//getters and setters

}
```

Using criteria builder I am able to do either of the things i.e. either get records from Person table based on cellNumber or get records from Person table based on cellNumber's in personal_information table

But I hope I have explained my problem properly, I would like to get records from both the tables based on cellNumber

Thanks in advance. Please let me know if there any information that is missing and you would like me post.

P.S. 
Something that I tried and did not work:

```
List<Predicate> predicates = Lists.newArrayList();
predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.or(
                    criteriaBuilder.like(person.get(Person_.cellNumber), 123456789),
                    criteriaBuilder.like(person.get(Person_.personalInformation).<Integer>get("cellNumber"), 123456789)
               ));
```

I have also tried using them separately.

```
predicates.add (criteriaBuilder.like(person.get(Person_.cellNumber), 123456789));
predicates.add (criteriaBuilder.like(person.get(Person_.personalInformation).<Integer>get("cellNumber"), 123456789))
```

Comment: so where is your attempt at writing Criteria (and your JPQL) ?

Comment: @NeilStockton I added whatever I had tried.

Comment: What was the generated JPQL and SQL with those predicates set in the "where" clause?

Comment: @NeilStockton  honestly have no clue how the JPQL(new to the technology) looks but I will post the sql generated soon. But I dont think that would help us backtrace to how to build the criteria query. Still I would post it soon.

Comment: `criteriaBuilder.like()` works with String-type properties and you intend to use it with Integers. That won't even compile. Why not use `criteriaBuilder.equal`? NB: is keeping a telephone number as an integer and not a string really a good idea?